# Javascript if statement in string using the back quotes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to include a an `if` inside a string which uses the `but I get an error`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'`

```
var condtionsInput = document.getElementById("condtitions-input").value;
document.getElementById("condtitions-input").value = "";
var selectedLevel = document.getElementById("condtitions-level").value;
cell1.innerHTML = `<input value="`+condtionsInput+`"></input>
                        <select>
                            <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
                            <option ` + if(selectedLevel == "Important") {'selected="selected"'} + ` value="Important">Important</option>
                            <option value="Support">Support</option>
                        </select>`;
cell2.innerHTML = "<button>X</button></td>";
```

I have tried a the ternary operator too

```
var condtionsInput = document.getElementById("condtitions-input").value;
document.getElementById("condtitions-input").value = "";
var selectedLevel = document.getElementById("condtitions-level").value;
cell1.innerHTML = `<input value="`+condtionsInput+`"></input>
                    <select>
                        <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
                        <option ` + selectedLevel == "Important" ? 'selected="selected"' : "" + ` value="Important">Important</option>
                        <option value="Support">Support</option>
                    </select>`;
cell2.innerHTML = "<button>X</button></td>";
```

Comment: `if` doesn't return a value, it's a statement, so it cannot be used for string concatenation. Your easiest options are to use the conditional operator `? :` or surround the whole string creation in an `if/else`.

Comment: I have tried the `? :` too. I maybe using them wrong though

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't use backticks and concatenate. Use the template literals provided by template strings. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info.

Comment: off-topic advice, it's better to move to any jsx-framework, than write such implementation, that help you in more convenient way manage html-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the major features of using string templates (aka the backtick) is that you can do interpolated strings. Consider the following alternative using a template instead of concatenation with a ternary operator instead of `if`.

```js
cell1.innerHTML = `<input value="` + condtionsInput + `"></input>
<select>
  <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
  <option ${(selectedLevel == "Important") ? 'selected="selected"' : ""} value="Important">Important</option>
  <option value="Support">Support</option>
</select>`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use concatenation with backticks ([templates literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)). use placeholders instead.

This example demonstrates a simple placeholder usage:

```js
const person = 'Billy'
const myStr = `Hello ${person}, how are you?`

// Outputs: Hello Billy, how are you?
```

This example demonstrates a template literal that has placeholder with a ternary operator that has as template literal with a placeholder.

```js
const num = 100 * Math.random()
const name = 'Billy'
const myStr = `Hello ${num > 50 ? `my name is ${name}`: 'anonymous person'}`

// Outputs:
// Hello my name is billy
// or
// Hello anonymous person
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). When you want to exicute an expression on Template literals you have to use it like:

```
`string text`

`string text line 1
 string text line 2`

`string text ${expression} string text`

tag`string text ${expression} string text`
```

Answer (score 0):

As @VLAZ said you are looking for the ternary operator:
condition ? [returns when true] : [returns when false]

```js
cell1.innerHTML = `<input value="`+condtionsInput+`"></input>
<select>
    <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
    <option value="Important" ` + (selectedLevel == "Important") ? 'selected' : '' + `>Important</option>
    <option value="Support">Support</option>
</select>`;
```

*note: parenthesis are not necessary, just trying to make the condition easier to read

Comment: thanks, I have tried you example but it is only printing the text `selected="selected` on the screen and `<input>` and the dropdown